# Do I need to add studs to install a floating vanity in this layout?

Tags: framing

The vanity will have one sink unlike in the picture, one piece, 48" wide.
The vanity position is exact, the distance between studs measurements are exact for the right side but aproximative for the left side where as you can see in the picture the studs are not plumb
Rendering
[image]
Rel life picture
[image]

The cabinet is this one
https://www.bathdepot.ca/48in-walnut-wall-mount-vanity-set-with-porcelain-top-essence-collection-vw4818-23wal-127.html

[image]

Comment: You haven't told us how the thing mounts. How would we know? Also, the studs available on the side wall are probably your biggest concern. There are probably  plenty on the back wall.

Comment: I wish I knew, please feel free to suggest, that is something that I will have to research but since fixing framing issues will be a thing that I have to do soon I am asking now about it.
I do not have the cabinet yet, I might end up building one mysef

Comment: Well I have to imagine that most floating cabinets can mount to studs in any position, so your scenario isn't odd in that sense. I'm not sure how we can answer, though.

Comment: Are the cabinets  or cabinet you plan on using called out to be used as a floating cabinet? Typically a standard cabinet is not built to hang off a wall supported only by the wall. Standard cabinets must rest on the floor or the back will rip out of them.

Comment: I added a link to the cabinet above
I will update the diagram indicating the side studs as @isherwood requested (used a stud detector to locate it, that wall is closed)

Comment: From the spec of the cabinet, it is designed to be mounted by a full length spanner cleat at the top of the cabinet.  it would appear that you would need to add studs for the right and left side to have the horizontal cleat fully supported.  You have enough studs in the middle.  Depending on how well the right side of the cabinet meet or is flush with the right side wall, you could add a couple of mounting bolts through the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have studs in standard(ish) locations on the back wall. You have a first stud at a fairly good location on the side wall. With this information and little else it's a reasonable bet that you'll be able to mount a typical cabinet that's intended to be used in a floating fashion without issue.

Comment: thank you! I did not think I will have to attach it to the side wall..do I need that ?

Comment: It would take a huge amount of strain off the back panel of your cabinet. Again, we can't know until we see your cabinet. We're throwing darts in the dark.

Comment: The cabinet is posted above the last picture see that link

Comment: Sorry, I missed your update. As that cabinet is a box product (assembled with hardware) I'd have low confidence in it working well as a floating unit. I don't interpret "wall mount" to mean "floating". However, I'm having trouble verifying that.

Comment: In reviewing the link to the cabinet you are looking at, all pictures shows the cabinet as floating without attachment to any side wall.  You should be safe just mounting to the back wall.  I would just make sure that the attachment point in the back of the cabinet is match to a wall stub.  Just add extra stubs where necessary to match the mounting point on the cabinet.

Comment: I  will try to approximate where the cabinet attaches to the wall and add some support framing behind (horiontal 2x4s ?)

Comment: The issue isn't backing in the wall. The issue is the structural integrity of the cabinet. Doesn't matter how well it's stuck to the wall if it collapses under its own weight.

Answer (score 2):

I followed your link to the vendor site, and located a [link to a PDF](https://www.baindepot.com/media/ftpbaindepot/pdf/VW4818-23WAL-127.pdf) containing installation instructions. It was under **Product Page > [Features & Specs] > Technical Specs**.

The installation instructions appear to show the cabinet mounting using a "French Cleat" system, with 4 screws through the supporting cleat, and 2 screws through the cabinet after hanging it from the cleat.

In the instructions, the mounting was to plastic hangers, commonly referred to as "drywall anchors". However, the drawings were stylized, so this is not definite.

Since you have studs available, I would suggest that you visit your local home center (or "home centre", eh?) and pick up some hex-headed lag bolts, along with a similar number of matching washers. You can mark the position of your studs during the renovation process (or go back later with a stud finder), then drill larger holes in the mounting cleat to sink the lags into your studs.

Beware, though: my experience with big-box store lags is that many of them are made of "Chinesium." You want to go one or two sizes up from what you think will work. If you're thinking 1/4" (6mm), then go 3/8" instead (9mm).

Also beware: if you and your significant other are likely to "get frisky" on this surface, make sure you look at how it's engineered. I suspect it's probably just melamine (particle-board, MDF), which would contra-indicate friskiness unless you're both "heroin chic".

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add any studs to the back wall, but I have provided additional hints if you want to make sure. 
Attached is a diagram for mounting your floating Vanity.  This should be more than enough to have the cabinet and sink be supported on the back wall.  Your cabinet comes with a 48” cleat that the cabinet hands off of.  The left sister stub or full stub is only needed if the left most stud is not exposed enough to provide a mounting point.  Also just use stronger screws ¼” or 5/16” to mount the cleat to the back wall studs.  I am guessing the approx. location of where the 48” end on the right side.

[image]
The cabinet corner bracket (not shown)  is used to prevent the cabinet from lifting off the cleat and is not used to directly support the cabinet.  If possible, screw the back of the cabinet to a stub on the right and left side.